# Search fails to find app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, search

My iPhone has the app *Economist* installed. I can find the app’s icon. A tap to that icon launches the app.

Yet when I swipe down on the Home Screen to display the search bar, and type in the word *Economist*, the app is not among the search results.

Other apps can be searched by name. Typing “sa” lists the *Safari* browser. Typing “co” displays the *Contacts* app.

Why does the search facility lose track of some apps? How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't know why this is occurring. But perhaps deleting the app from your phone, and downloading it again from the App Store, will cause iOS to re-index the phone's app content.

Comment: Isn’t that an answer instead of a comment @DavidRecallsMonica ?

Comment: @bmike I suppose it could be, but it's only a guess on my part, so I was reluctant to offer it as an answer. Should I? Your answer is much more precise...I didn't even know there was a toggle for view-in-search.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is a preference for the app. Head to the settings app, Siri & Search.

Inspect an app that behaves well (you mentioned Safari)

[image]

Then inspect the problematic app.

I would toggle everything off, then only toggle on **Show App in Search** and then test. Then re-enable everything you want for the Economist.

---

In some off cases, you might have an actual spotlight issue. Setting the device in airplane mode and then powering it down cleanly then restarting is what I’d try next. Open a support case if those two steps don’t work, making a full backup once you know the basics aren’t functioning.